# Need help, I stuck when install (VGAM) and how to use mlogit. I don't understand from that pdf example

Tags: r, logistic-regression, multinomial, mlogit, vgam

I need help for my problems. I have 2 problems.

1. I can't install library (VGAM) on my RStudio. Have any idea for another regression logistic ordinal package or have solution for my problem?
   [image]
2. I Stuck for the first step when used mlogit. I have dependent variable = Kategori.Kredit with 3 option. And I have independent variable = FD,FC,ND,NC,CASA. Please help me to solve this problem, I try read example on pdf but still didn't understand.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Please, don't post two completely different questions at the same time.
Don't post code as image. Post as text
About number 2, it seems that your data is in the wide format, while mlogit need it in the long one. Use the function mlogit.data to get your data ready.   The manual has some good examples about mlogit.data